# How to select last entries for each groups?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
ID | team1 | team2 | Date
-----------------------------
1  |   36  |   25  | 2019-01-05
2  |   25  |   39  | 2019-01-07
3  |   36  |   39  | 2019-01-09
4  |   36  |   11  | 2019-01-10
5  |   11  |   25  | 2019-01-11
6  |   25  |   36  | 2019-01-12
```

How to get last 2 entries for team 25 and 36. Good result is:

```
ID | team1 | team2 | Date
-----------------------------
4  |   36  |   11  | 2019-01-10 > 36
5  |   11  |   25  | 2019-01-11 > 25
6  |   25  |   36  | 2019-01-12 > 25 & 36
```

25 and 36 is just for example. We can have a long list of teams, as well as a very large list of entries. If the search would be carried out on one column, for example team1 then the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    ID, team1, team2, `Date`,
    CASE WHEN @id != team1 THEN @rownum := 1 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 END AS rank,
    @id := team1
FROM matches
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id := NULL) r
WHERE team1 IN(25, 36)
OREDER BY team1, `Date` DESC
) WHERE rank <= 2
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Mysql version 5.7

Comment: Specifcally, you want the last result for team 25 (minus 36), the last result for team 36 (minus 25), and the last result shared by them both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to join the table against itself for later games, and discard any rows where there is a layter game:-

```
SELECT a.*
FROM matches a
LEFT OUTER JOIN matches b
ON a.team1 = b.team1
AND a.`date` < b.`date`
WHERE b.id IS NULL
AND   a.team1 IN (25, 36)
```

Comment: Note that this solution is cool (it's called a 'strawberry query' after all ;-) ), but it doesn't scale particularly well.

Comment: (Besides, this appears to be a bit different from what the OP is requesting)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your query to the UNION of the 2 columns and join to the table you will get the result that you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.* 
FROM matches m INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT team, `Date`, 
      CASE WHEN @id != team THEN @rownum := 1 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 END AS rank,
      @id := team
    FROM (
      SELECT team1 team, date FROM matches
      UNION ALL
      SELECT team2, date FROM matches  
    ) t  
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id := NULL) r
    WHERE team IN (25, 36)
    ORDER BY team, `Date` DESC
  ) t  
  WHERE rank <= 2
) t ON t.`Date` = m.`Date` AND t.team IN (m.team1, m.team2)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ceWWMRS1T83Tcjg6FMH9tD/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | team1 | team2 | Date                |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ------------------- |
| 4   | 36    | 11    | 2019-01-10 00:00:00 |
| 5   | 11    | 25    | 2019-01-11 00:00:00 |
| 6   | 25    | 36    | 2019-01-12 00:00:00 |
```